# C++ string function only returning certain chars

Tags: c++, string, char, backslash

```
for(int i = 4 * scale; i > 0; i--) {
    x = -1 * i + 6;
    c = string(x, '/\\'); // Why Won't you work! It only prints the "\" no "/"
    cout << "\\_" << c << "/\\" << c << "_/" << endl;
}
```

Above is a section of my code. My question is why does it only print the \ symbol and ignores the / one. It would be greatly appreciated if  someone could answer this and if you need more information that I may have forgotten to leave in this post just leave a comment and I will add it to the post

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to use `"` rather than `'`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have more than one character in a character constant.

The compiler you are using seems to treat the two-character constant as a two-byte integer where the high byte is the character / and the low byte is the character \. When you assign it to a char the higher bytes are lost, like in a normal int-to-char  assignment. That's why you get only the last character.

Comment: `more than one character in a character constant.`, sounds like oxymoron to me